# Regex question!

Tags: regex, string, variables, newline

I'm not too familiar with regex but I know what I need to find-

I have a long list of data separated by newlines, and I need to delete all the lines of data that contain a string "(V)". The lines are of variable length, so I guess something to do with selecting everything between two newline characters if there's a (V) inside?

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: How long is the “long list”? Is it small enough to fit in your available physical memory a few times over? If so, it's not “long” and you can process the lot in memory just fine. If not, time to use line-by-line processing. (For some languages, e.g. Perl, line-by-line makes best sense anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for this regular expression:

```
^.*\(V\).*$
```

Explanation:

```
^   start of line
.*  any characters apart from new line
\(  open parenthesis (escaped to avoid special behaviour)
V   V
\)  close parenthesis  (escaped to avoid special behaviour)
.*  any characters apart from new line
$   end of line (not strictly need here, included only for clarity)
```

Depending on your language you may need to add delimiters such as `/` and/or quotes `"` around the regular expression and you may need to enable multiline mode.

Here's an online example showing it working: [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/snjnsLM6a4)

Answer (score 1):

If the data is indeed rather large, then running a single regex against the whole string would be a bad idea.  Instead, a simple solution like this Perl script could work for you:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt' or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ m/\(V\)/) {
        next;
    }
    print $line;
}
close $fh;
```

This script reads the data file one line at a time and prints the lines that do not contain "(V)" to stdout.  (You obviously could replace the "print" with a different data processing task)

Answer (score 1):

Use the UNIX command `grep`, if you have access to such a system.

```
$ grep -v '(V)' data.txt
```

Grep matches all lines containing "(V)" in data.txt, and shows only the lines not matching (`-v`).